# The frequency occurrence of primes in the unique prime factorization of natural numbers.

Tags: number-theory

I am curious about the frequency of occurance of prime numbers in natural numbers. For example starting with the first non-prime 4 = 2^2, then 6 = 2x3, 8 = $2^3$, 9 = $3^2$ etc. Now of course a prime can not be a factor of a number $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Thus taking prime factorization of larger numbers to see some more interesting sets of primes.

1674 = $2^1 \times 3^3 \times 31^1$

1675 = $5^2 \times 67^1$

1676 = $2^2 \times 419^1$

and so on. I am wondering if there has been research done on the frequency of primes. I have found much about how prime numbers themselves are distributed among the natural numbers - but nothing about the frequency of their occurrences as constituents of numbers.

Thanks for any insight, or references to this subject matter.

Thanks,

Brian

Comment: The prime $3$ is a factor of one third of natural numbers.

Comment: What does _"Now of course a prime can not be a factor of a number $n\in \mathbb{N}$"_ mean?

Answer (score 7):

The frequencies are straightforward to determine: asymptotically, $\frac{1}{p}$ of numbers are divisible by $p$, $\frac{1}{p^2}$ of numbers are divisible by $p^2$, and so forth. It follows that the distribution of the exponent of $p$ in a prime factorization is asymptotically [geometric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution): the probability that it is exactly $k$ is

$$\frac{1}{p^k} - \frac{1}{p^{k+1}} = \frac{p - 1}{p^{k+1}} = \frac{p-1}{p} \frac{1}{p^k}.$$

You can ask other interesting statistical questions about prime factorizations, too, like: about how many distinct prime factors does a positive integer $n$ have, on average? The answer is given by the [Hardy-Ramanujan theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%E2%80%93Ramanujan_theorem), and a more precise description of the statistical distribution is given by the [Erdős–Kac theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Kac_theorem), but I won't describe the answers because it's possible to at least guess the average number based on the above calculation and a nice fact about primes you may already know.